# Intermittently Oracle SYSDATE is inserted as UTC Time

Tags: oracle11g

I have a stored procedure in Oracle 11g that inserts a record into a table as follows:

```
    INSERT INTO X_ZAV_XML_RESULTS COLUMNS 
    (BACKGRND_SVR, RECORD_IN_DATE,
    SITE_ACCESSION_KEY, XML_MESAGE_CONTENT, RECORD_OUT_DATE) VALUES 
    (vClientName, SYSDATE, vTestNumber, XMLResults, SYSDATE);
```

Intermittently we have noticed that on some records, the RECORD_OUT_DATE is set to the UTC time. This procedure is run on several servers and we have seen the problem on all servers. What could I be missing?

Sorry, this is all the information I have on this issue. I am not very familiar with the settings on the server that may cause this issue.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show an example of the data.  SYSDATE is the time on the server's OS.  How are you querying the results back to determine there is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps casting your date to specific timezone solve your problem. Try something like this(check that i use GMT, but you can use another):

```
INSERT INTO X_ZAV_XML_RESULTS COLUMNS 
    (BACKGRND_SVR, RECORD_IN_DATE,
    SITE_ACCESSION_KEY, XML_MESAGE_CONTENT, RECORD_OUT_DATE) VALUES 
    (vClientName, cast(sysdate as timestamp) at time zone 'GMT', 
    vTestNumber, XMLResults, cast(sysdate as timestamp) at time zone 'GMT');
```